# Django 1.11 Model Migration Operations doesn't apply

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

My operation inside my migration is executed, whereas nothing happened into the database concerning the payer field.

Here's my model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, WithCsvImportMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),
                              unique=True, blank=False)
    external_id = models.CharField(_('external id'), db_index=True, max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    payer = models.CharField(_('payer'), max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
```

The first migration concerning the payer field:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.6 on 2018-11-15 21:58
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('authenticate', '0012_auto_20181112_1631'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='payer',
            field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='payer'),
        ),
    ]
```

And this is the one that is executed but the result doesn't seems to be applied to the database:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.6 on 2018-11-15 22:01
from django.db import migrations, transaction

from xxx.authenticate.models import User # The xxx is here to replace the actual application name

def create_payer_names(apps, schema_editor):
    with transaction.atomic():
        for user in User.objects.all():
            if user.external_id != "":
                user.payer = user.external_id
                user.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('authenticate', '0013_user_payer'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_payer_names, migrations.RunPython.noop, atomic=True),
    ]
```

My database is already populated, and each user has an `external_id`

```
>>> from xxx.authenticate.models import User
>>> for item in User.objects.all():
...     print(item.external_id)
... 
043819FZAFR
762944FZAFR
285895FZAFR
671800FZAFR
924618FZAFR
068805FZAFR
232544FZAFR
130978FZAFR
412568FZAFR
600003FZAFR
254624FZAFR
417745FZAFR
068280FZAFR
031971FZAFR
141936FZAFR
>>>
```

And here is the empty result of previous migrations:

```
>>> for item in User.objects.all():
...     print(item.payer)
... 























>>>
```

Here's the output for the command : `manage.py showmigrations`

```
authenticate
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20171103_1722
 [X] 0003_auto_20171109_1206
 [X] 0004_auto_20180329_1049
 [X] 0005_auto_20180507_1123
 [X] 0006_user_by_pass_generates_invoice
 [X] 0007_auto_20180524_1732
 [X] 0008_auto_20180530_1525
 [X] 0009_auto_20180801_1644
 [X] 0010_user_payment
 [X] 0011_remove_user_payment
 [X] 0012_auto_20181112_1631
 [X] 0013_user_payer
 [X] 0014_auto_20181115_2301
```

And when I do:

```
./manage.py migrate authenticate 0014
```

The output is the following:

```
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and why the migration operation isn't applied as it's supposed to be?

Comment: I can't see what the problem is, but you should definitely not be importing User from your actual model code; in migrations you should always get the frozen version, so `User = apps.get_model('authenticate', 'User')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm already doing it, I just changed it for this SO post in order to be more understandable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the migration, you should use `apps.get_model` to get the `User` model. See the docs on [data migrations] for more info.

```
def create_payer_names(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('authentication', 'User')
    with transaction.atomic():
        ...
```

The output of showmigrations is showing that migration 0014 has already been applied. That's why you get the `No migrations to apply` message.

```
 [X] 0014_auto_20181115_2301
```

You could re-run the 0014 migration by faking back to the 0013 migration first.

```
./manage.py migrate --fake authenticate 0013
./manage.py migrate authenticate 0014
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it actually works pretty well! I didn't know about `--fake`

It worked on my local environment. When I'm going to push to another environment, will I need to do the same command or will it be applied automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure which command you expect to be applied automatically. We used `--fake` because `showmigrations` showed that `0014` had been applied, and you wanted to undo that so you could re-run migration 0014. You should run `showmigrations` in your other environment as well, and decide whether or not you need to use `--fake`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights !